# Selenium Python giving a 401 possibly due to proxy authentification

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium with a custom profile which I called selenium and set it up so it would not ask a proxy password when starting a new Firefox.

Then in Python 2.7, I am using this script.

```
from selenium import webdriver    

myprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("C:\Users\MeMeAndMe\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\yxc5xxxm.selenium")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=myprofile) # Get local session of firefox
```

The last line gives a 401, but the browser is absolutely fine. If I type www.google.com in the browser, it will go on the page without any pop ups. Because of this, I am unable to assign the new browser instance to `browser`.

Anyone encountered something similar ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SRC\NuffieldLogger\NuffieldLogger\nuffield_selenium.py", line 9, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=myprofile) # Get local session of firefox
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 114, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 136, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>pxgsc1 - Access Denied - 401</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><IMG src="http://ieconfig.sig.echonet.uk.net.intra/images/logo-en.png" alt="MicroTosh"><p><FONT color=red face=Verdana size=4> Access Denied</font><br>\r\n<FONT color=black face=Verdana size=2><br>Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.<br><br>For access please contact Client Services.</p>\r\n<p><B>Technical Data</B><br><ul><li>URL: http://127.0.0.1:63286/hub/session<li>IP: 10.2.15.231<li>Proxy: pxgsc1<li>Category: none<li>Error: 401 - authentication_failed</ul>This is typically caused by an incorrect username and/or password, but could also be caused by network problems.</FONT></p></BODY></HTML>\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `http://ieconfig.sig.echonet.uk.net.intra` part of that 401 is a dead giveaway that it is a proxy issue.

According to the [WebDriver doc](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy)...

You can set a proxy by

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "localhost:8080"

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "noProxy":None,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect":False
}

# you have to use remote, otherwise you'll have to code it yourself in python to 
# dynamically changing the system proxy preferences
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER)
```

Comment: I will test this on Monday. Thanks for the heads up. Strangely enough with the C# version of the Selenium library, I do not have an exception on this line.

Comment: Is the `"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"` some placeholder for anything? Or it should be exactly this?

Comment: that url represents a grid that would be running by command: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -role hub`  so wherever the grid is running, it will be `http://<url>:4444/wd/hub`